# RxSwift Observable Array Sorting

Tags: swift, sorting, observable, rx-swift

I am trying to sort an observable array and havent had any luck (RxSwift n00b)

```
let items = [AnyObject]? 
let locations = Observable.just(items)
```

I want to achieve something like this on locations

```
items.sortInPlace({$0.name < $1.name})
```

Any pointers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured

1. initing locations as `Variable([AnyObject]())`
2. setting locations `asObservable`
3. sorting as `locations.value.sortInPlace({$0.name < $1.name})`

Feels good!

Answer (score 7):

here my solution

```
Observable
   .just(items)
   .map({ (items) -> [AnyObject] in
       return items.sorted(by: { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
          return item1.name < item2.name
       })
   })
   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

(Swift 4) This is working for me where datasource is a Variable array

```
var datasource = Variable<[String]>.init([])

_ = self.datasource.value.sort(by: {$0.name < $1.name})
```

Hope it helps